# Counting maximum element present in all continuous subarrays

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

An array A consisting of N positive integers. There are  `N × (N+1) / 2` non-empty continuous subarrays of the array A .

We have to Count the  maximum element present in all continuous subarrays.
**For Example:**

```
1 2 3 
Subarray List :
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1,2]
[2,3]
[1,2,3]

Maximum Element :
[1]
[2]
[3]
[2]
[3]
[3]
```

**My Approach:**
Using `Segment Tree` Query The maximum element Present in a interval
**Code:**

```
public static void get_max_freq(int a , int b , ArrayList<Long> freq ,ArrayList<Integer> P , int n , int[] A){

      if(a>b) return;

    int index = query(1,0,n, a, b, A);  // Segment Tree O(Logn)

    long temp = (index-a+1)*(b-index+1);
    freq.add(temp);
    P.add(A[index));

    get_max_freq(a,index-1, freq, P, n, A);
    get_max_freq(index+1, b, freq, P,n, A);

}
```

I wondering is my solution is correct if the elements are not unique in an array.
 Is there ant faster and better solution than this.

Comment: If your code works, but you are looking for improvements you should ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO.

Comment: Before answering do know that this is from an online contest !

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overcomplicating it. To construct a segment tree you will need `O(nlogn)` space and you will do this in `O(n)` time. After this you will need to answer your `n(n+1)/2` queries each of which will take O(logn), so basically you it will cost you `O(n^2*logn)`.

Bruteforce approach (get all intervals and calculate the maximum on each of them) would run in `O(n)` memory and `O(n^3)`.

But you can calculate all the maximums with the following easy algorithm. Let your array be `[a0, a1, a2, ..., an]`. Start with 0-th element and calculate all their maximums on the range starting with this element: `max(a0-a0), max(a0-a1), ... max(a0-an)`. You can do this in `O(n)`, just because `max(ai-an) = max( max(ai-a(n-1)), an)` (previous maximum and current element). So you calculate the values for a0, then a1 and so on in `O(n^2)`. You can store them and then grab output them in the format you want. You ended up with `O(n^2)` space and time with a super easy algorithm.

**P.S.** notice that you can not do better than `O(n^2)` in time, because you need to at least output `n*(n+1)/2` elements, so you can only hope to reduce space complexity.

Comment: `O(n^2)` will not work as N is `10^6` and my approach is `O(nlogn)` and `A` is the original array of size `N` not `N*(N+1)/2`

Comment: @SunnyPathak how exactly your approach is `nlogn`? You need to answer `n^2` queries, each of them is `logn`. Does not look like `nlogn` in total to me