# Segment Tree in solving the subarray

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to Solve this [Problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRYS03/)

**Statement:**
For a given sequence A(A1,A2……AN), your task is to find the sum S of the minimum elements of all the possible contiguous sub-sequences of A

**Example:**

```
1 2 3
Possible contiguous sub sequences {(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3)}
Sum of minimum elements = 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 10
```

I am using **Segment Tree** to solve this problem. I am Querying about a minimum element in a range then solving recursively on the remaining index.

Code:

```
public static long get_me_baby(int a , int b  , int n , long[] A){

      if(a>b) return 0;

    int index = query(1,0,n, a, b, A);
    long temp = (index-a+1)*(b-index+1);
    return  A[index]*temp +get_me_baby(a,index-1,  n, A)+get_me_baby(index+1, b,n, A);

}
```

[Full Working Code](http://ideone.com/rLZUdF)

I am very frustrated why i am getting the wrong answer. I have tried Hundreds of time but still not getting correct answer , i don't know where i have made a mistake.
Please Help me

Comment: you asked a slightly different question, providing the same solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/31886608/1090562